# Invisible recaptcha is visible

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I have an invisible recaptcha and it's work but it's totally visible to all the users. And I mean this:

[image]

And my console says:

```
Uncaught Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey
at new jl (VM19165 recaptcha__ru.js:575)
at new $Y (VM19165 recaptcha__ru.js:584)
at mt (VM19165 recaptcha__ru.js:599)
at VM19165 recaptcha__ru.js:590
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at hE (VM19165 recaptcha__ru.js:590)
at rI (VM19165 recaptcha__ru.js:593)
at ib (VM19165 recaptcha__ru.js:585)
at VM19165 recaptcha__ru.js:600
at VM19165 recaptcha__ru.js:620
```

My js code is:

```
function onSubmit(token) {
alert('thanks ' + document.getElementById('fields[Email]').value);
}

function validate(event) {
event.preventDefault();
grecaptcha.execute();
}

function onload() {
var element = document.getElementById('submit');
element.onclick = validate;
}


<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

And html is:

```
    <input type="text" id="fields[Email]" value="" name="fields[Email]" class="add_field" placeholder="Email" />
<div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXcTqa9o5k"  data-callback="onSubmit" data-size="invisible">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-bs">   
  <button type='submit' id='submit' class="sub-rassilka" >SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
```

What's the problem, what did I missed?

UPD: I changed the api line to this one, but have the same error in console and recapcha is still shows itself

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_6LcaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXcTqa9o5k" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the api with this line :

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

You don't passe your site key like :

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=site_key" async defer></script>
```

Reference : [reCAPTCHA v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3)

You can get your site key [here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create)

---

When you do this :

```
grecaptcha.execute()
```

you need to pass the site key too, like :

```
  grecaptcha.execute('site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
     ...
  });
```

[source](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#integration)

Comment: I did as you told but stll the same :(

Comment: @StanDan You have the same error message ? Can you show me your new code with an edit of the op ?

Comment: Updated question for you!

Comment: @StanDan I think "reCAPTCHA_" is not necessary in the site key